# What is the right redirection in Django?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm a beginner in Django and I want to display the username from the nav bar. I did not use User authentication. I only created custom database table called Jobseeker:

```
class Jobseeker(models.Model):

    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    repassword = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
    def __str__(self):
       return self.username
```

Because the criteria is the user should be able to login using username or email then password. I was able to achieve that using this code,

```
def login(request):

    jobseeker = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        userinput = request.POST['username']
        try:
            username = Jobseeker.objects.get(email=userinput).username
        except Jobseeker.DoesNotExist:
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            jobseeker = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if Jobseeker is not None:
            auth.login(request, jobseeker)
            messages.success(request,"Login successfull")
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Invalid credentials, Please check username/email or password. ')
    
    return render(request, 'login.html',)
```

Now my problem is using {{request.user}} in the nav bar it display the superuser's username, instead on the jobseeker username. [Superuser's username](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5r3f.png). [Code for the HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsPv1.png)

I want to display the username that i inputed in the login form. [It should be one of these username that needs to be displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzLly.png)
sorry for the bad english but hopefully it makes sense.

Comment: Add code directly. Not just screenshot

Comment: sorry im new to stack over flow i will edit it.

Comment: Is the problem only to display jobseeker name in navbar?

Comment: yes, but it display superuser

Comment: sorry, i did not know that..

Comment: ok fine no problem.

Comment: @Selfcontrol31 checkout my answer and try that

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give me enough informations.

Up to now, I can only explain why the problem occurs when you login with email: it is because `auth.authenticate` function is only called when the code in `try` raise an error.

So you should fix like this:

```py
jobseeker = None
if request.method == 'POST':
    userinput = request.POST['username']
    try:
        username = Jobseeker.objects.get(email=userinput).username
    except Jobseeker.DoesNotExist:
        username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    jobseeker = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if jobseeker is not None:
        auth.login(request, jobseeker)
        messages.success(request,"Login successfull")
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        messages.error(request,'Invalid credentials, Please check username/email or password. ')

return render(request, 'login.html',)
```

If it still works badly, please comment to my answer and I'll help you more.

Comment: it doesn't work it displays 'Invalid credentials, Please check username/email or password. even when i input the right data